# Update RCP over Windows Service

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-rcp, p2

I want to update my RCP with a Windows Service (.jar) who will check an UpdateServer for newer version. This would look like this:
[image]

Afterall I need a few hints for this steps:

- Get RCP version in Update.jar
- Get Installation path from RCP in Update.jar
- Use p2 updater with Update.jar for updating the RCP

If someone would have some hints or perhaps a better approach, I would reall appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy colors! .)

1. it should not matter how you start your updater: as a service or from any task scheduler
2. p2 director application does everything what you request. you have just to configure it properly
3. you have to take care in case you want to update a running application and if the application is going to start in the middle of such update. do you really need such design?